# Why is using this code to replace a formula giving me an error?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

In Excel I use the following to clear cell E5 and replace it with the word name.

```
Sheets("Invoice").Range("E5") = "Name"
```

I can also use the following to replace G11 with the VLOOKUP code I have here and this works.

```
Sheets("Invoice").Range("G11") = "=VLOOKUP(B11,INVENTORY!A$1:D$2501,INVENTORY!C$1,FALSE)"
```

Problem is when I use,

```
Sheets("Invoice").Range("G11") = "=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(B11,INVENTORY!A$1:D$2501,INVENTORY!C$1,FALSE)),"",(VLOOKUP(B11,INVENTORY!A$1:D$2501,INVENTORY!C$1,FALSE)))"
```

I am getting an debug error and the only thing I can figure is the quotes I have in the center of the code is playing havoc with the quotes they use at the beginning and end of the VB code.

Answer (score 0):

In VBA a `"` is used to enclose a string. To use a `"` inside a string, use `""`. What goes wrong in your formula is that VBA converts the middle two quotes to one quote. If you replace the `""` in the middle with `""""`, you should be good to go.

See [this Stack Overflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216616/how-to-create-strings-containing-double-quotes-in-excel-formulas) for reference.

Answer (score 0):

If just changing the quotes from "" to """" doesn't fix it then maybe you should try setting the value property of the range object, instead of the range object itself.

```
Sheets("Invoice").Range("G11") = "=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(B11,INVENTORY!A$1:D$2501,INVENTORY!C$1,FALSE)),"",(VLOOKUP(B11,INVENTORY!A$1:D$2501,INVENTORY!C$1,FALSE)))"
```

Your are trying to set the Range Object to a string value your equation.  What you probably want to do is set the **.text**, **.value**, or **.formula** property to equal "name" or you formula. ( also like @agtoever mentioned you need to change "" to """" )

Try it this way:

```
Sheets("Invoice").Range("G11").value = "=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(B11,INVENTORY!A$1:D$2501,INVENTORY!C$1,FALSE)),"""",(VLOOKUP(B11,INVENTORY!A$1:D$2501,INVENTORY!C$1,FALSE)))"
```

Using **.formula** or **.text** might also work, but i just looked at one of my workbooks and this is how I have it working.